# Store database on external storage only in debug

Tags: android

Is there a way to write databases on external storage only in debug mode? By this I mean that:

1. I already have the necessary code to know if I am in debug, so I can already do:

   ```
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "track.db";

   public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
       super(context,
             Utils.isDebug(context) ? 
                          Utils.getAppExtDir() + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME : 
                          DATABASE_NAME, 
             null, 
             DATABASE_VERSION, 
             R.raw.ormlite_config);
   }
   ```
2. So I would like to only require the permission when debugging:

   ```
   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
   ```

Comment: If you are using Gradle for Android (with or without Android Studio), put the extra permission on a copy of `AndroidManifest.xml` in a `debug/` sourceset, to have it only be applied in `debug` builds. Also, note that `BuildConfig.DEBUG` exists to tell you if you are doing a debug build or not.

Comment: My `AndroidManifest.xml` is in `app/src/main`. Do you have some link on how a debug sourceset is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you have some link on how a debug sourceset is defined?

It is covered in the [tools site's coverage of Gradle for Android](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types).

Create a `app/src/debug/` directory and put an `AndroidManifest.xml` in there. The contents of that manifest will be merged with the contents of your manifest in the `main` sourceset, according to [the manifest merger rules](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger), when you are doing a `debug` build. It will be ignored for a `release` build.

So, in principle, if your `debug` sourceset's manifest has the `<uses-permission>` element you want for debug only, that should get merged in.

I'll readily admit that I have not tried this, and so while the documentation indicates that it should work, there may be bugs (in Gradle for Android or the docs) that prevent it from working.

Comment: Thanks it works; I created the new `AndroidManifest.xml` in `app/src/debug` containing only `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>`, then I added an empty `debug { }` build type in `build.gradle`, and then I removed the permission from the common `AndroidManifest.xml` and it seems to work, ie the permission is only requested for the debug apk.

Comment: I _think_ adding the debug build type is superfluous, but I might be wrong and I am too lazy to verify.

Comment: @isonix: The `debug` and `release` build types are pre-defined, so you do not need the empty `debug {}` closure. If you wanted to change other properties of the debug build, you could do it in the closure.